# Remove diffgram and NewDataSet tag from XML in c#

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I want to remove the `diffgram` and `NewDataSet` tag from xml.

```
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
 <NewDataSet>
  <MACNET diffgr:id="MACNET1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
    <BATCH_ID>131070</BATCH_ID>
    <BATCH_Date_Submitted>12/1/2014 7:36:06 AM</BATCH_Date_Submitted>
    <BATCH_Date_Received>12/1/2014 7:36:06 AM</BATCH_Date_Received>
  </MACNET>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

I have generated this xml from `dataset` by XmlSerializer. I have used following code.

```
           //Serialize dataset
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                ns.Add("", "");

                using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
                {
                    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataSet));
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, ds, ns);
                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
                }
            }
```

I want to remove `<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">` and `<NewDataSet>` tag from `xml`. and also want to remove `diffgr:id="MACNET1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"` from **MACNET** tag. How can I remove this?

I want following type of **output**

```
<MACNET>
<BATCH_ID>131070</BATCH_ID>
<BATCH_Date_Submitted>12/1/2014 7:36:06 AM</BATCH_Date_Submitted>
<BATCH_Date_Received>12/1/2014 7:36:06 AM</BATCH_Date_Received>
</MACNET>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is to serialize the `DataSet` via the [`DataSet.GetXml()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.getxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`DataSet.WriteXml()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`DataTable.WriteXml()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods, rather than trying to serialize the `DataSet` with an `XmlSerializer`.  This skips all the `diffgram` nonsense and produces the following output:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <MACNET>
    <BATCH_ID>131070</BATCH_ID>
    <BATCH_Date_Submitted>12/1/2014 7:36:06 AM</BATCH_Date_Submitted>
    <BATCH_Date_Received>12/1/2014 7:36:06 AM</BATCH_Date_Received>
  </MACNET>
</NewDataSet>
```

Now, depending on how you created your `DataSet`, the `<NewDataSet>` root node might not be present, and you are done.  But if the `<NewDataSet>` node is present, and you want to generate an XML string without it, you can use the `RootlessDataSetXmlWriter` suggested here: [Save a DataSet ds.WriteXml(…) without `<NewDataSet>` Tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442437/save-a-dataset-ds-writexml-without-newdataset-tag/9232306#9232306), with an added constructor that accepts a `TextWriter`:

```
public class RootlessDataSetXmlWriter : ElementSkippingXmlWriter
{
    private readonly string _dataSetName;

    public RootlessDataSetXmlWriter(TextWriter stream, string dataSetName)
        : base(stream, (e) => string.Equals(e, dataSetName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        _dataSetName = dataSetName;
        this.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented;
    }

    public RootlessDataSetXmlWriter(Stream stream, string dataSetName)
        : base(stream, (e) => string.Equals(e, dataSetName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        _dataSetName = dataSetName;
        this.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented;
    }
}

public class ElementSkippingXmlWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    private Predicate<string> _elementFilter;
    private int _currentElementDepth;
    private Stack<int> _sightedElementDepths;

    public ElementSkippingXmlWriter(TextWriter writer, Predicate<string> elementFilter)
        : base(writer)
    {
        _elementFilter = elementFilter;
        _sightedElementDepths = new Stack<int>();
    }

    public ElementSkippingXmlWriter(Stream stream, Predicate<string> elementFilter)
        : base(stream, Encoding.UTF8)
    {
        _elementFilter = elementFilter;
        _sightedElementDepths = new Stack<int>();
    }

    // Rest is as shown in the linked answer.
}
```

And then call it like

```
        string xml;
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        using (var writer = new RootlessDataSetXmlWriter(textWriter, ds.DataSetName))
        {
            ds.WriteXml(writer);
            xml = textWriter.ToString();
        }
```

This gives the following output:

```
<MACNET>
  <BATCH_ID>131070</BATCH_ID>
  <BATCH_Date_Submitted>12/1/2014 7:36:06 AM</BATCH_Date_Submitted>
  <BATCH_Date_Received>12/1/2014 7:36:06 AM</BATCH_Date_Received>
</MACNET>
```

which is what you require.  Note, however, if your root `MACNET` table has more than one row, the XML produced will be invalid, since [all XML documents must have one and only one root tag](http://www.xmlfiles.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp).

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried your code. But it removes my schema. I don't want to remove it.

Comment: @AjayPunekar - try using the [`ds.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.xmlwritemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload.

Comment: @AjayPunekar - or, use [`ds.WriteXmlSchema(writer)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a1f26zy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to write the schema into a separate string, in case you are having trouble with multiply-rooted XML documents.